# Android Studio how to create working APK

Tags: android, android-studio, build, export, apk

I have an Android Studio Project and I need to create a runnable apk file for my beta testers (I pass the apk to them directly (via mail)). I tryed both to build an unsigned APK and to generate a signed one. But when I or my beta testers try to intall the APK, the installer say "App not intalled".

How can I build an APK file which work?

Thanks for help.

Comment: your testers are downloading and installing from beta play store? or you are giving them apk directly?

Comment: I need to give them the apk directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having seen you case, you need to make sure that you are trying or installing signed apk. I was facing the same issue of **App not installed** what I did to over come the issue I build signed apk. And everything worked fine. Although the version before 3.0, without signed apk used to work, but after 3.0 or above without signed apk(if you installed directly) will not work. This will throw the same App not installed error.

Comment: NOTE: Further more you need to make sure that the same app is not already installed in your device. (Accidently it may happen that you install the app from you development machind and generate the apk and then you try to install the same apk. This may give the same error).

Comment: I tryed to install a signed apk after had uninstalled the app, but it still gave me the error :(

Comment: :) my idea is you must be missing any step. But I am glad that worked for you. Happy coding